# How to populate these J comboboxes in java programming?

Tags: java, combobox

I want to populate three j comboboxes  with  using array lists and if,elseif,else condition.if i select a  Depertment  from  first depertments J combobox.then the semesters will be selected one by one in the second j combobox depending on the selection from Depertments j combobox.then if i select A semester from Semesters jcombobox.then the all semesters book will be  Seleted  depending on the  semester selection from  Semesters jCombobox.Like this Screenshot example.[Java J Comboboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqHmT.png)

```
String[] dep={"Select Depertment","Compurter","Civil","Electrical","Telecom"};
String[] Compurter={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Civil={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Electrical={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Telecom={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};


String[]FirstSemester={"Select BooK Name","English1","Engineering Drawing","Mathematics-1","Chemistry","Computer Fundamental","Basic Electricity","Basic Electronics"};
String[]SecondSemester={"Select BooK Name","English 2","Physical Education","Physics-1","Mathematics-2","Computer Application-1","Bangla","Electronic Device & Circuit-1","Basic Workshop Practice"};
String[]ThirdSemester= {"Select BooK Name","Programming Language-1","Computer Application-2","Digital Electronics-1","Industrial Electronics","Mathematics-3","Physics-2","Social Science-1"};
String[]FourthSemester={"Select BooK Name","Programming Language-2","CAD & Graphics Design","Digital Electronics-2","Data Structure & Algorithm","Electrical Circuits & Machine","Discrete Mathematics","Social Science-2"};
String[]FifthSemester={"Select BooK Name","Microprocessor & Microcomputer-1","Computer Architecture","Programming Language-3","Database Management System","Web Design","Book Keeping & Accounting","Environmental Management"};
String[]SixthSemester={"Select BooK Name","Microprocessor & Microcomputer-2","Computer Peripherals","Data Comm. & Computer Network-1","Computer System Software","Computer Servicing","Web Development","Business Org. & Communication"};
String[]SeventhSemester={"Select BooK Name","Embedded Systems & PLC","Multimedia & Graphics","System Analysis & Design","Data Comm. & Computer Network-2","Computer Engineer Project","Industrial Management","Entrepreneurship"};        

public LibraryManage() {
    initComponents();

    divcomboDepertment.removeAllItems();

    for(int i=0; i< dep.length;i++) {
        divcomboDepertment.addItem(dep[i]);
    }   




    for(int i=0; i< Compurter.length;i++) {
        divcomboBook.addItem(Compurter[i]);
    }       

 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        divcomboDepertment = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        divcomboSemester = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        divcomboBook = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtSubmit = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 204, 255));

        jLabel1.setText("Depertment:");

        jLabel2.setText("Semester:");

        jLabel3.setText("Books:");

        divcomboDepertment.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        divcomboDepertment.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                divcomboDepertmentItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        divcomboSemester.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        divcomboSemester.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                divcomboSemesterItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        divcomboBook.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(141, 141, 141)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(divcomboSemester, 0, 335, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(divcomboDepertment, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(divcomboBook, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(divcomboDepertment, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(divcomboSemester, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(divcomboBook, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(84, 84, 84))
        );

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 51));

        txtSubmit.setText("Submit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(273, 273, 273)
                .addComponent(txtSubmit)
                .addContainerGap(315, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(txtSubmit)
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void divcomboDepertmentItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    divcomboSemester.removeAllItems();

        if(divcomboDepertment.getSelectedIndex() !=0)
        {
            String[] c;

            if (divcomboDepertment.getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                c=Compurter;
            }
            else if(divcomboDepertment.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                c =Civil;
            }
            else if(divcomboDepertment.getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                c=Electrical;
            }

           else 
            {
                c=Telecom;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
            {
                divcomboSemester.addItem(c[i]);
            }
        }     


    }                                                   

    private void divcomboSemesterItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
          divcomboBook.removeAllItems();

        if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex() !=0)
        {
            String[] b;

            if (divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                b=FirstSemester;
            }
            else if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                b =SecondSemester;
            }
            else if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                b=ThirdSemester;
            }
           else if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==4)
            {
                b=FourthSemester;
            }
           else if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==5)
            {
                b=FifthSemester;
            }
           else if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex()==6)
            {
                b=SixthSemester;
            }
           else 
            {
                b=SeventhSemester;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
            {
                divcomboBook.addItem(b[i]);
            }
        }     

    }
```

I am writing my Source codes like the above Example.But my program is not working properly.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You start by writing down code. We cant help with stories or ideas about code; we can only help with specific questions. In other words: study the excellent tutorials from Oracle on how to use such UI elements ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html ) and start coding. And then, when you are stuck with a specific problem ... come here and ask for help. But we are not here to teach how to this stuff from start to end.

Comment: And then: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the few things it takes to create human radable text. Like: correct syntax and usage of spaces, "casiness" and paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to be honest I didn't really look through all your code but I did utilize your String Arrays within the code example I provide below. I hope I didn't misinterpret anything here.

The ideal situation in a case like this is to try and make things as fool proof as possible for the User. What I mean by this is, don't give the User the opportunity to make a mistake in his/her selections from the displayed JComboBoxes. You can do this by basically clearing and disabling all combo boxes (Semester selection and Books selection) until an actual Department has been selected. If all selections are made and the User decided to change their mind before submitting those selections by changing any selection then the all combo boxes after that selection box are cleared and or disabled until the appropriate selections are made. As a matter of fact, your Submit button should also be disabled until all three combo boxes contain a valid selection and maintained that way within the **ItemStateChanged()** event for each combo box. In any case....

Now, for some reason you have way more String Arrays than you really need, for example:

```
String[] Compurter={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Civil={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Electrical={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
String[] Telecom={"Select Semester","FirstSemester","SecondSemester","ThirdSemester","FourthSemester","FifthSemester","SixthSemester","SeventhSemester"};
```

All these arrays contain exactly the same string elements. Not needed since you only require one array to actually fill the Semester ComboBox. We can accomplish this by utilizing a single String Array (let's call it semesters):

```
String[] semesters={"Select Semester","First Semester","Second Semester","Third Semester",
                    "Fourth Semester","Fifth Semester","Sixth Semester","Seventh Semester"};
```

I understand why you did this but honestly, it's not required and you'll see why in a minute. You'll also notice that I spaced things properly within each element so that it looks more appealing within the Semesters ComboBox.

In all your String Arrays which contain Book Titles (**firstSemester[]**, **secondSemester[]**, **thirdSemester[]**, etc) there is no reference whatsoever to the Department for which each book title might relate to. Some Books may relate to more than one Department or perhaps even to all Departments for some titles. You need to supply a means in which a we will know which title can relate to which Department.

I have done this by modifying the elements in each Array by adding the related Departments to each elemental string using a semicolon (**;**) delimiter just so you don't need to go into a 2 dimensional Array, for example a array element might contain:

```
"Engineering Drawing;Civil;Electrical"
```

Here the first token is always the Book Title, and any other tokens are the Departments that Book Title will relate to for that semester. There could very well be an element that contains:

```
"Basic Workshop Practice"
```

This Book Title only relates to that particular Department selected within the Department combo box. Each elemental string is split using the String.split() method so as to retrieve the Book Title and the related Department which was selected within the Department combo box. I have added a method named **addBooksToComboBox()** which takes care of this business (see code below) and places the appropriate Book Titles within the Book combo box for the Department and Semester selected.

Here is the code:

```
//Place under your class constructor:
String[] dep = {"Select Depertment","Computer","Civil","Electrical","Telecom"};

String[] semesters={"Select Semester","First Semester","Second Semester","Third Semester",
                    "Fourth Semester","Fifth Semester","Sixth Semester","Seventh Semester"};


String[] firstSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","English1;Civil;Telecom","Engineering Drawing;Civil;Electrical",
                               "Mathematics-1;Computer;Civil;Electrical;Telecom","Chemistry;Civil",
                               "Computer Fundamental;Computer;Civil;Electrical;Telecom","Basic Electricity;Electrical",
                               "Basic Electronics;Electrical"};

String[] secondSemesterBooks ={"Select Book Name","English 2;Civil;Telecom","Physical Education;Computer;Civil;Electrical;Telecom",
                               "Physics-1;Civil","Mathematics-2;Computer;Civil;Electrical;Telecom",
                               "Computer Application-1;Computer","Bangla;Telecom","Electronic Device & Circuit-1;Electrical",
                               "Basic Workshop Practice;Civil;Electrical"};

String[] thirdSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","Programming Language-1;Computer","Computer Application-2;Computer",
                               "Digital Electronics-1;Electrical", "Industrial Electronics;Electrical","Mathematics-3;Civil;Electrical",
                               "Physics-2;Civil","Social Science-1;Civil"};

String[] fourthSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","Programming Language-2;Computer","CAD & Graphics Design;Computer;Civil",
                                "Digital Electronics-2;Electrical", "Data Structure & Algorithm;Computer",
                                "Electrical Circuits & Machine;Electrical","Discrete Mathematics;Civil",
                                "Social Science-2;Civil"};

String[] fifthSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","Microprocessor & Microcomputer-1;Computer;Electrical",
                               "Computer Architecture;Computer;Electrical","Programming Language-3;Computer",
                               "Database Management System;Computer","Web Design;Computer","Book Keeping & Accounting;Civil;Telecom",
                               "Environmental Management;Civil"};

String[] sixthSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","Microprocessor & Microcomputer-2;Computer;Electrical",
                               "Computer Peripherals;Computer;Electrical", "Data Comm. & Computer Network-1;Computer",
                               "Computer System Software;Computer","Computer Servicing;Computer;Electrical",
                               "Web Development;Computer","Business Org. & Communication;Civil"};

String[] seventhSemesterBooks = {"Select Book Name","Embedded Systems & PLC;Electrical","Multimedia & Graphics;Computer",
                                 "System Analysis & Design;Computer;Civil","Data Comm. & Computer Network-2;Computer",
                                 "Computer Engineer Project;Computer","Industrial Management;Civil;Telecom",
                                 "Entrepreneurship;Computer;Civil;Electrical;Telecom"};   

// *******************************************************
// * I have added the Departements to Book Titles. It's up to YOU to make *
// * sure they are correct!                                                                 *
// *******************************************************


// JButton used to load up the Department ComboBox
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    divcomboDepartment.removeAllItems();
    divcomboSemester.removeAllItems();
    divcomboBook.removeAllItems();
    divcomboSemester.setEnabled(false);
    divcomboBook.setEnabled(false);

    for(int i=0; i< dep.length; i++) {
       divcomboDepartment.addItem(dep[i]);
    }  

}  

private void divcomboDepartmentItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    divcomboSemester.removeAllItems();
    divcomboBook.removeAllItems();

    if(divcomboDepartment.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        divcomboSemester.setEnabled(false);
        divcomboBook.setEnabled(false);
        return;
    }
    String depName = divcomboDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString();
    for(int i=0; i< semesters.length;i++) {
        divcomboSemester.addItem(semesters[i]);
    }
    divcomboSemester.setEnabled(true);
}

private void divcomboSemesterItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    divcomboBook.removeAllItems();
    String department = divcomboDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(divcomboSemester.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        divcomboBook.setEnabled(false);
        return;
    }
    String[] semesterBooks = null;
    String semesterStrg = evt.getItem().toString(); 
    if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("first semester")) { semesterBooks = firstSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("second semester")) { semesterBooks = secondSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("third semester")) { semesterBooks = thirdSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("fourth semester")) { semesterBooks = fourthSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("fifth semester")) { semesterBooks = fifthSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("sixth semester")) { semesterBooks = sixthSemesterBooks; }
    else if (semesterStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("seventh semester")) { semesterBooks = seventhSemesterBooks; } 
    else { return; }

    addBooksToComboBox(divcomboBook, semesterBooks, department);
    divcomboBook.setEnabled(true);
}

private static void addBooksToComboBox(final JComboBox combo, final String[] semesterArray, final String department) {
    for(int i = 0; i < semesterArray.length; i++) {
        String booksStrg = semesterArray[i];
        if (booksStrg.contains(";")) {
            String[] depts = booksStrg.split(";");
            for (int j = 0; j < depts.length; j++) {
                if (depts[j].equalsIgnoreCase(department)) {
                    combo.addItem(depts[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        else { combo.addItem(booksStrg); }
    }
}
```

Hope this assists you or others in some way :)